# Spread column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

Hi i would like to change my data frame `profile_table_long` which represents 24 hour/data for 50 companies from 2 years.

Data - date from 2015-01-01 to 2016-12-31

name - name of firm 1:50

hour - hour  1:24 (with additional 2a between 2 and 3)

load - variable

```
x <- NULL
x$Data <- rep(seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2016/12/31"), "days"), length.out=913750)
x$Name <- rep(rep(1:50, each=731), length.out=913750)
x$hour <- rep(rep(c(1, 2, "2a", 3:24), each=36550),length.out=913750)
x$load <- sample(2000:2500, 913750, replace=T)
x <- data.frame(x)


         Data name hour     load
1  2015-01-01    1    1   8837.050
2  2015-01-01    1    2   6990.952
3  2015-01-01    1    2a  8394.421
4  2015-01-01    1    3   8267.276
5  2015-01-01    1    4   8324.069
6  2015-01-01    1    5   8644.901
7  2015-01-01    1    6   8720.878
8  2015-01-01    1    7   9213.204
9  2015-01-01    1    8   9601.976
10 2015-01-01    1    9   8549.170
11 2015-01-01    1    10  9379.324
12 2015-01-01    1    11  9370.418
13 2015-01-01    1    12  7159.201
14 2015-01-01    1    13  8497.344
15 2015-01-01    1    14  6419.835
16 2015-01-01    1    15  9354.910
17 2015-01-01    1    16  9320.462
18 2015-01-01    1    17  9263.098
19 2015-01-01    1    18  9167.991
20 2015-01-01    1    19  9004.010
21 2015-01-01    1    20  9134.466
22 2015-01-01    1    21  7631.472
23 2015-01-01    1    22  6492.074
24 2015-01-01    1    23  6888.025
25 2015-01-01    1    24  8821.283
25 2015-01-02    1    1   8902.135
```

I would like to make it look like that:

```
    data     hour   name1   name2 .... name49 name50
2015-01-01     1     load   load ....   load  load
2015-01-01     2     load   load ....   load  load
.....
2015-01-01     24    load   load ....   load  load
2015-01-02     1     load   load ....   load  load
.....
2016-12-31     24    load   load ....   load  load
```

I tried `spread()` from `tidyr` package `profile_table_tidy <- spread(profile_table_long, name, load)` but I am getting an error `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows`

Comment: Try doing `distinct` from `dplyr` before `spread`.

Comment: @Gopala how should I do that ? `distinct` remains only unique values - in my case all values are uniqe.

Comment: It is not clear to me that your posted data is accurate. You have duplicate row numbers. After correcting for that, your command works for me. If you don't have any duplicate rows in your data, your command should work. Can you post the exact data you have?

Comment: @Gopala sorry it took so long, my whole data looks like that: `x <- NULL
x$Data <- rep(seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2016/12/31"), "days"), each = 1250)
x$Name <- rep(1:50, each=731)
x$hour <- rep(c(1, 2, "2a", 3:24), each=36550)
x$load <- sample(2000:2500, 913750, replace=T)
x <- data.frame(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method uses the reshape2 package:

```
    library("reshape2")
    profile_table_wide = dcast(data = profile_table_long, 
                               formula = Data + hour ~ name, 
                               value.var = "load")
```

You might also want to choose a value for `fill` as well. Good luck!

Comment: Almost! dataframe looks like it should (structure) but on places where load values should be there are only 1 and 0 :(